# Is "} while (0);" always equal to "break;} while (1);"?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, break, do-while

I have compared gcc assembler output of

```
do { 

// some code 

} while (0);
```

with

```
do {
 
    // some code

    break; 
} while (1);
```

The output is equal, with or without optimization but..

It's always that way?

No experiment can prove theories, they can only show they are wrong

Comment: Why are you putting code into a while loop that doesn't loop?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you would need to do that?  In other words, what's the purpose of the do...while construct if you just wish to run the block of code once?

Comment: The logic may be that under certain conditions a "continue" will be called, looping again.

Comment: It is a replacement for using goto's: break on exit-conditions.  When refactoring, it pays to use extra functions instead and return when needed.

Comment: @Markus, if continue is called in a `do while` does the condition get checked before it loops again?

Comment: @jinguy - Absolutely. Continue causes the condition to be checked and if false the loop is aborted.

Comment: Then, if continue is called in the loop, the behavior will be different. (@Markus, @jmucchiello)

Comment: `do { }  while (0)` is a common idiom for writing Macros.  It produces more compile errors than the alternatives, when used improperly... as for the `while (1)` with `break`... I have no idea why that would be useful.

Comment: @jjnguy @Amardeep read to @stefaanv, that's the reason you can exit the block just with a break, it's a great way of make clean C code, for example testing many functions output and breaking whenever one of them return false, like a try-catch block without needing exceptions

Comment: do { } while ( false ) is a great way to not create huge if/else ladders.  On error you break with a flag set.

Comment: @Hernán Eche: The question is tagged C and C++. Which is it? If C++, then you have exceptions so you don't have to worry about doing without them.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, you still can choose not to use exceptions, more in an embedded enviroment where resources are minimal.

Comment: @Hernán Eche: Personally, I don't buy the argument that exceptions are necessarily significantly more resource intensive than the alternative. I would (and do) buy the argument that some environment's support for exceptions is not robust or complete and this is found more often on embedded environments, but this means that your are coding with something less than C++. Anyway, you haven't answered my question. Are you asking about C or C++?

Comment: @Charles Bailey, My question apply to both

Comment: @Hernán Eche: Your question might apply to both lanuages, but which are you actually asking about? It's obvious that some of the help that people are trying to provide depends on which you are actually asking about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a slight difference:

```
do {
  // code
  if ( condition )
    continue;
  // code
  break;
} while(1);
```

Will restart the loop when `condition` is true, whereas in the `} while(0);` version, the `continue` will be equivalent to `break`.

If no `continue` is present, then they should produce exactly the same code.

Comment: Maybe they won't produce the same code, but they should do about the same thing.

Comment: can be always changed into something like: `do { /*code*/ } while(condition); /*code*/` at least, that specific example

Comment: @ShinTakezou Yes; the only practical reason might to use multiple conditions, and/or interlaced breaks.

Answer (score 5):

The forms are not equivalent.  This is an infinite loop:

```
do {
    continue;
    break;
} while (1);
```

This isn't:

```
do {
    continue;
} while (0);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**  Upon reading various comments on the matter, I will admit that this answer is wrong.  Sorry.

Instead of:

```
do{ 

//some code 

}while(0);
```

or:

```
do{

//some code

 break; 
}while(1);
```

I would just use:

```
//some code
```

I'm not 100% sure if you can do this in c++, but if you want to limit the scope of variables, and that is why you are doing this, just use curly braces by themselves:

```
{

 // Some Code

}
```

Comment: What if you want to break or continue?

Comment: No, I don't want to limit the scope, it's for using break inside the block and reach the end

Comment: @jmucchiello: Use a `goto`. No seriously. Using a fake loop so that you can disguise a `goto` as some other word is more evil than using `goto` in the first place. (IMHO)

Comment: @jmucchiello I suppose I didn't consider that case.  It seems to me that using other flow of control statements (if, then, else) would be more logical.  But, then again, I don't think like a c programmer.

Comment: @Hernan If that is the case, then I think you should be using if/else blocks to achieve this.  Or, even better, put the code into a method and use return to break out of the code early.  Using a loop to do the job of if/else blocks seems broken to me.

Comment: @jjnguy: Why do you think this answer is wrong? It looks like a perfectly sensible answer to me.

Comment: @Charles, The loop construct is being used for different reasons that what I thought when I first answered.  It now makes perfect sense why someone would want to do this. (But, i still don't think it's a good idea)

Comment: @jinguy:  The main use I've seen for `do { ... } while 0` is in macros, since it allows you to write a single statement that contains multiples.  A block is not quite equivalent to a single statement, since `{ ... };` is two statements while `do { ... } while 0;` is one (and that can matter:  consider `if (foo) bar(); else baz;`).  This is mostly applicable in C, because C++ has better ways to write function-type macros.

Comment: @David Thornley: I fully agree that it's a "good" C macro solution (if you have to be writing function-style macros, but I don't think that that's the situation in the question. @jjnguy: I still think you are correct to suggest not using an actual loop where a loop isn't the logical construct required.

Answer (score 4):

Markus' comment pointed me to this answer: the difference is when using `continue` keyword.

In this case:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        ++i;
        _tprintf(_T("Iteration %d\n"), i);
        if (i < 30) continue;
    } while(0);

    return 0;
}
```

you get **only one** iteration, while in this case:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        ++i;
        _tprintf(_T("Iteration %d\n"), i);
        if (i < 30) continue;
        break;
    } while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

you get **30** iterations. Tested under VS2008.

Comment: Karasu: I had to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c to understand your code =P, yes that's the difference

Comment: @Hernán Eche: Sorry for the inconvenience. I use Microsoft's VS2008 for all my work :)

Answer (score 3):

The do while clauses are logically equivalent. If they are translated to the same byte code depends on the compiler at hand. I guess that most modern compilers will treat them equally.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT based on your comment that you're using a while with `break`s in order to be able to break out of the 'loop' when certain conditions have been met.

If this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
do
{ 
  // processing step 1
  if( some_condition )
    break;
  // processing step 2
  if( some_condition )
    break;
  // etcetera..
} while(0)
```

...then just break the code you have in your while loop out to a stand-alone function with multiple returns:

```
void processing()
{

  // processing step 1
  if( some_condition )
    return;
  // processing step 2
  if( some_condition )
    return;
  // etcetera..
}

int main()
{
  // ...
  processing();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1: making assumptions.   do whiles can be used to exit early from a chain of functions calls (setup for instance) without an if/else ladder.

Comment: @gbrandt:  Look again.  It was completely unclear what the OP wanted until the "assumptions" were pointed out to the OP.

Comment: removed -1 on rewording of answer.