# static main from static class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out why this is not working. I want to do like in Java where main is a static function in a class but this is producing unresolved external symbol error:

```
 static class MainClass
{
     public:
    static int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Why doesn't this work?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting `_tmain()` inside a class?

Comment: C++ is not java...

Comment: Why do people have to try to program *"like in language X"*? If in rome, ...

Comment: Tried compiling your code using Code:Blocks on Windows(g++), and I get "error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions". Just adding this for the reference of others. Not really  providing an answer.

Comment: First of all you cannot use static for class declaration. Second, main (or _tmain) is not supposed to be declared as pointer to function.

Comment: I am quite sure that `static class` is not correct Java either...

Comment: And this is why I wrote my profile.

Comment: `static class` is correct in C++, but it should read `static class OptionalName { ... } NAME;`. He misses the name afterwards. The `static` appertains to the declarator, not the the class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ does not work like that.
You need main as a function:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    //STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `_tmain` is mangled in the binary with the class name `MainClass` in it, so multiple classes could have a function `_tmain` in them and not conflict. It's not got the same mangled name as `::_tmain` is going to have.

I remember that with an earlier version of MSVC, it accepted the following without a linker error which ended up accidentally as a result of macro expansion in my code base once

```
namespace bar {
  int main() { }
}
```

It apparently treated the name `main` specially and didn't mangle it or mangle it the same as `::main`. But such a thing is not Standard conformant. Like in the class case, such a function is completely unrelated to the *main function*.

Answer (score 1):

_tmain is called from CRT. You need to set in your linker an entry point to another function that will call MainClass::_tmain instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in C++, you cannot put an entry point inside a class. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c/895894#895894) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't that work?  Because it's not C++.

```
struct MainClass {
  static int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return MainClass::main(argc, argv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really C++, so much as the standard linker process which is looking for an export of a specific name (with C-style linkage). The specific export varies based on the compiler and executable type, but the format is specific for each type. For example, Windows GUI exe's have different entry points than console, and specific for ASCII or UNICODE. But the linker is always looking for a function with a specific link name, which is why a static member won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You always need `main()` defined as a global function. This is where the program always starts in C++. You could simple call your static class function from main and pass on the variables if you really want to:

```
class MainClass
{
     public:
    static int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   return MainClass::_tmain(argc, argv);
}
```