# C++, command line args not being parsed properly

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line-arguments

I have a program:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::cout << "STARTING" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Num inputs: " << argc << std::endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
```

that I expect to print out all the command line arguments.  However, the output is this:

> > ./Test.exe hello world
>
> STARTING 
>   Num inputs: 3 
>   . 
>   h 
>   w

It appears that it's only looking at the first char in each argument and not the entire char* till termination character.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Additional Notes: Creating it through VS2008, and I am essentially copying and pasting an example on the internet that should work.  I have run the program in bash, powershell, and cmd.

Comment: I beleive `_tmain()` expects `tchar`

Comment: Does it still happen if you put a `main` function in your program?  IE, after you change the name of `_tmain`...

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

Answer (score 17):

Your Visual C++ project is set to Unicode, and your main function is called _tmain. This means that Windows invokes your function and passes you Unicode strings, but you're treating them as ANSI strings by using the char* type. Since the second byte of the first Unicode character is null, this appears as an ANSI string with one character.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I changed my project settings to multi-byte character set and it works.  THANKS!

Comment: @jbu so might want to set it as the correct answer. A checkbox below the votins buttons.

Comment: Sigh...that isn't exactly the lesson you should have learned from this but OK.

Comment: @Noah, what do you mean?  he gave me an understanding of how unicode characters are represented at a low level and why my project is incorrectly parsing it.  Is there another lesson to be learned here that I'm not getting?

Comment: @jbu - if you're going to use _tmain, follow the signature of _tmain.  Otherwise stick with the standard program entry point: main.

Comment: You should use `_tmain` or `wmain` instead of `main`, and you should avoid the legacy MBCS settings. Unicode is the standard setting for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely it's compiled with `UNICODE` settings.  You should be using `wcout` instead of `cout` if `UNICODE` is defined.  And all strings should be put inside `_T()`.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define tout wcout
#else
#define tout cout
#endif 

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
   std::tout << _T("STARTING") << std::endl;
   std::tout << _T("Num inputs: ") << argc << std::endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
       std::tout << argv[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: or, alternatively, assuming that `_UNICODE` is always defined (MBCS builds aren't really necessary any more since Windows 9x died long ago), use `wmain` and `wchar_t` everywhere.

Comment: Also note that `wcout` still doesn't work, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/10/07/10072032.aspx

Answer (score 4):

First char? That smells like Unicode being interpreted as ANSI. It makes sense. If you use _tmain then you have to use TCHAR.

Answer (score 3):

Are you compiling your code in Unicode mode?

Comment: This is another correct answer.  I changed my project settings to multi-byte character set and it works.  THANKS!

Comment: @jbu: Don't do this, you'll lose Unicode functionality. The MBCS mode is only for backwards compatibility.