# why name mangling isn't breaking my program?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, function-signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is main() overloaded in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408183/is-main-overloaded-in-c)

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void* a, void* b)
{
    std::cout << "hello standalone " << std::endl;                      
    return 0;
}
```

different parameters should have a different symbol name after name mangling(`void* a, void* b)` should be different from `(int, char**`), but this program doesn't have any problem when running.

Why is that?

Comment: You must have a very basic compiler not to complain about this code

Answer (score 5):

Because `main` is a special case, and the compiler generates special code for it.  Typically, `main` will be called from a startup routine—often called `crt0` in older compilers—written in C, so the compiler will generate `main` as if it were declared `extern "C"`.  But that's in no way required; it's a just a typical implementation.

Comment: Do you have any reference to prove it's a specia case?

Comment: Interesting [crt0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) has a wikipedia article.

Comment: Typical `nm` output: `000000000040dca9 T main`; which confirms it is not mangled at all.

Comment: @new_perl §3.6.1 in the standard.  The description of `main` is pretty clear, and it describes something that is _not_ a normal C++ function.

Comment: @JesseGood It's a very poor article, since it suggests something universal, although the very name indicates that it has its origins in C.  In fact, `crt0.o` was the name in early Unix of an object file which specified a start address for the executable, and called a C function `main`.  When C++ came along, it "mangled" `main` as if it were a C function, so that `crt0.o` could call it.  And some of the early implementations inserted extra code at the start of `main` to call constructors.

Comment: @MatthieuM. And under Windows, `dumpbin` displays `_main`, which is the mangling C uses under Windows (and under most Unix---just not Linux).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the compiler. The standard required signatures for main are:

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char** argv)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

But besides these, the compiler is free to provide other signatures as well.

For example, gcc 4.3.4 rejects your code - http://ideone.com/XZp2h

MSVS complains about unresolved externals.

Comment: It seems it always works,no matter what the signatures are, is `main` treated specially in compilers?

Comment: @new_perl it depends on the compiler.

Comment: oops I just found I'm using `llvm-g++-4.2` not gcc..BTW how can there be more than one standard signatures??

Comment: @new_perl Compiler magic.  The usual solution is to treat `main` as if it were `extern "C"`, but a compiler could do more or less anything it wants, as long as the required behavior is met.