# Why is main method not mangled similar to other methods

Tags: linker

In the following program I want to know why main is not mangled similar to other methods:

```
int main()
{

}

int main1() 
{

}
```

If I check the out of nm I see the main method is not mangled while main1 is. I tried to change the program entry from main to main1 using #pragma entry but it had not effect.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: backward compatibility? I guess the linker searches for a not mangled `main`.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715689/why-name-mangling-isnt-breaking-my-program

Comment: Then why changing the entry point of the program using #pragma entry has no impact on it?

Comment: based on the suggestions, I did further read on the #pragma behavior. Seems like pragma support is compiler dependent and I found -Wunknown-pragmas flag supported by g++ to see if the pragma is understood by g++ compiler. Seems like compiler doesn't support #pragma entry or #pragma comment(linker...) and so the main() method is not mangled while main1() is in spite of changing the entry point to main1().

Answer (score 0):

> If I check the out of nm I see the `main` method is not mangled while `main1` is.

The `main` symbol is *special* in several respects:

- you can't take its address
- you can't call it yourself
- it *must not* be mangled because the standard C runtime library will call it by unmangled `main` name.

So it's not mangled because the C++ standard requires that. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408230/50617).