# How does main() handle a variable number of arguments without ellipses?

Tags: c++, c

How does the `main()` function handle a variable number of arguments without the use of ellipses (`...`)? For processing variable number of arguments, last argument to the function should be `...` which is not the case with the `main()` function.

Comment: It gets a pointer to an array of char*...

Comment: Simply google the signature for `main` i.e. there is lots of question on this site for this question for starters

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: It doesn't cause an issue if the calling code supplies more parameters than the called function expects, if the calling code is responsible for restoring the stack after return based on number of parameters passed. The unused parameters are just ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `main()` is special, and it has two standard-defined forms:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
int main(void)
```

The system may support other forms; it is common that the environment is also made available:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
```

These forms are fixed.  The only unusual thing is that a system must support either of the first two (and some systems support others as well).

The variable number of command line arguments is handled via an array of pointers to strings (that's `argv` above), unlike say [`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html) from POSIX.

See also:

- [How does the `main()` function in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419569/how-does-the-main-method-work-in-c)
- [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336)

---

[rahul manglani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4272745/rahul-manglani) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587658/how-does-main-handles-variable-number-of-arguments-without-ellipses/27587681#comment43600102_27587681):

> The two links you mentioned made it pretty clear. There are different possible approaches listed there, which of them is actually being used is not mentioned.

In a sense, it doesn't matter; the system simply has to work, and the people who produce 'the system' must make it work.  You as the programmer using the system don't need to know how it works; you can simply assume that it does work.

Behind the scenes, what usually happens is that the 'start' function which calls `main()` does some fixup work (in the case of a C++ program in particular, a lot of fixup work — such as ensuring all the constructors that must be executed before `main()` starts are in fact executed), but ends with a fixed sequence such as:

```
exit(main(argc, argv, environ));
```

Note that `environ` is a global variable, `extern char **environ;` (which is unique among the global variables defined by POSIX in that no header declares it) and it contains the pointers to the environment variables.  The 'start' code has to ensure that is set; it is trivial to pass `environ` as an argument to `main()`, therefore.

This calls `main()` with a fixed argument list and calls `exit()` if/when it returns.  Indeed, Apple takes it a step further and passes a fourth argument to `main()`.  If the called function was defined as `int main(void) { … }`, it simply ignores the arguments it was passed; if it was defined as `int main(int argc, char **argv) { … }`, it can access the command line arguments as usual; if it was defined as `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) { … }`, then it can access the environment too.

Generally, the systems are set up so that extra arguments don't cause damage.  This is a reason why C is unusual in its calling conventions and it's why the called function doesn't clean up the arguments pushed onto the stack — the called function doesn't know how many arguments were actually pushed onto the stack.  It assumes that the ones it expects were provided and uses those without problems, but the calling code knows what it pushed so it can clean up properly.  The biggest problems occur if the called function expects N arguments but the caller passes M arguments and M < N.  (There are also issues of types pushed and the sizes of those types, etc, but that's a second-order problem.)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. The two links you mentioned made it pretty clear.
There are different possible approaches listed there, which of them is actually being used is not mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ main takes 2 parameters, typically called `argc`, and `argv`. The `argv` parameter  is an array of `argc` `char` arrays. Command line arguments are passed to the program in `argv`. There are variations on this theme with the exact number of parameters, but main's signature is generally

```
int main(int argc, char **argv);
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted this question to mean: how is it possible that `main` can take either zero arguments or two arguments?

While the details are obviously implementation-dependent, on most implementations, the default C calling convention is that the caller cleans the stack. Therefore, the code that calls `main` is at perfect liberty to always push two arguments onto the stack (`argc` and `argv`), whatever the declaration of `main` might be. If `main` is declared with no arguments, then `main` simply won't access the values of the arguments it receives. After `main` returns, the calling code clears the stack.

It should be pointed out that `main` isn't even special in this sense. Try this:

```
int printf();
int main() { printf("Hello, world!\n"); }
```

The C compiler will happily allow you to call `printf` even though, lacking an `#include <stdio.h>` directive, it has no idea how many arguments `printf` actually wants. Presumably, the code that calls `main` is conceptually something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv); /* declare "main" */
main(argc, argv);                /* call "main" */
```

If the definition of `main` actually specifies zero parameters, this still works (although I believe it would technically be undefined behaviour if you *actually* did this).

In the case of C++, although the linkage of `main` is left unspecified by the standard, most implementations simply treat it as though it has C linkage, so the name is not mangled and everything above still applies.

Answer (score 0):

It handles it by accepting an array and array length set as variables `argc` and `argv`

you may find more data here:

http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html