# I'm not able to use scanf() in else statment

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

can we use scanf() function in else , like i used in this code.
Bec i'm not able to enter value(char) for sex variable.
so i want to why i'm not able to enter the value for sex variable ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();

    int age;
    char s,ms;

    printf("Please enter M if you are married or U if you are un-married\n");
    scanf("%c", &ms);

    if(ms=='M')
        printf("\nyou are recruted");
    else if(ms=='U')
    {
        printf("\nenter sex- A for male & B for female\n");
        scanf("%c",&s);

        if(s=='A')
        {
            printf("\nEnter your age\n");
            scanf("%d",age);

            if(age>30)
                printf("\nYou are selected");
            else
                printf("\nYour age is less for this job");
        }
        else if(s=='B')
        {
            printf("\nEnter your age\n");
            scanf("%d",age);

            if(age>25)
                printf("\nyou are recruted");
            else
                printf("\nyour age is less to be recruted");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter A for male or B for female");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PLEASE ENTER THE CORRECT VALUE\n please enter M for Married or U for un-married");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Output :

```
Please enter M if you are married or U if you are un-married
U
enter sex A for male or B for female
Please enter A for male or B for female
```

Comment: You should always test the result of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) which gives the number of *successfully scanned items*

Comment: BTW, don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanf skips every other while loop in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enter the data in the first read of this scanf:

```
scanf("%c", &ms);
```

A newline character remains in the keyboard. To solve this put a space in your second scanf:

```
scanf(" %c",&s);
```

This is to consume any trailing character in the `stdin` that might have been left by previous user input (like the `carriage return`), before the `scanf` reads the user input. Also note that you missed the `&` in `scanf("%d",age);`:

Also note [`main` should return `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419569/how-does-the-main-method-work-in-c/19419617#19419617).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()    
{   
    int age;    
    char s,ms;    
    printf("Please enter M if you are married or U if you are un-married\n");    
    scanf("%c", &ms);        
    if(ms=='M')    
        printf("\nyou are recruted");    
    else if(ms=='U')  
    {    
        printf("\nenter sex- A for male & B for female\n");
        scanf(" %c",&s);    
        if(s=='A')   
        {    
            printf("\nEnter your age\n");    
            scanf("%d",&age);    
            if(age>30)    
                printf("\nYou are selected");    
            else    
                printf("\nYour age is less for this job");    
        }    
        else if(s=='B')    
        {    
            printf("\nEnter your age\n");    
            scanf("%d",&age);    
            if(age>25)    
                printf("\nyou are recruted");    
            else    
                printf("\nyour age is less to be recruted");    
        }    
        else    
        {    
            printf("Please enter A for male or B for female");    
        }    
    }
    else    
    {    
        printf("PLEASE ENTER THE CORRECT VALUE\n please enter M for Married or U for un-married");    
    }    
    getchar();    
    return 0;
}
```

Read [`Why is adding a leading space in a scanf format string recommended?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391465/why-is-adding-a-leading-space-in-a-scanf-format-string-recommended)

Comment: Thankyou. I have one more doubt.
Why int main() instead of void main(). I'm confused with return(0) , and i searched about return many times but still not getting the perfect answer. same here why are we using return(0) here ?

Comment: @SharadGaur - There are not only operating systems' architecture which vary but also hardware platform architecture. Hence to keep a standardized way of writing code `C` and `C++` were standardized by ISO. They mandate that `main` should return `int`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add a `&` when input the age value and you can use `getchar()` to deal the new line in buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    char s,ms;
    printf("Please enter M if you are married or U if you are un-marriedn");
    scanf("%c", &ms);
    getchar();       // deal with thre newline in buffer
    if(ms=='M')
    printf("nyou are recruted");
    else if(ms=='U')
    {
        printf("nenter sex- A for male & B for femalen");
        scanf("%c",&s);
        getchar();    // deal with thre newline in buffer
        if(s=='A')
        {
            printf("nEnter your agen");
            scanf("%d",&age);    // add & when you use scanf
            if(age>30)
            printf("nYou are selected");
            else
            printf("nYour age is less for this job");
        }
        else if(s=='B')
        {
            printf("nEnter your agen");
            scanf("%d",&age); // add & when you use scanf
            if(age>25)
            printf("nyou are recruted");
            else
            printf("nyour age is less to be recruted");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter A for male or B for female");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PLEASE ENTER THE CORRECT VALUEn please enter M for Married or U for un-married");
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Besides, `int main()` and `return 0;` is better.

Comment: What about the newline left in the buffer?