# int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

what is the difference between int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) and int main(int argc, char** argv)?

I am not clear of the difference.

Answer (score 7):

_tmain is the Microsoft-specific wrapper around "main()".  You can use it with either 8-bit ASCII or 16-bit Unicode.  Here's the MS documentation for it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> You can also use _tmain, which is defined in TCHAR.h. _tmain  will
>   resolve to main unless _UNICODE is defined, in which case _tmain  will
>   resolve to wmain.

Answer (score 2):

`_tmain` is the unicode version of main. I think this is a MS only extension though.