# t_main causing non-portable programs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

I often see people using massively visual studio to write programs in c++.
So massively that they think that "visual c++" is the programming language thay are using.
This is how often I see to declare a main:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

What's the purpose of that? is that only to make fellow-windowers 's programs non-portable on other platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. Just not experienced programmers and Microsoft thinking it is the king of the world, he can adjust standards to it's own liking.

More:

[What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a duplicate question that belongs in a close-vote and an unnecessary comment.

Comment: Do it if you please. I did a quick sumary and posted link.