# Understanding _tmain in Visual C++ console projects

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual C++ 2008 Express, when I create a new console project I get the following program to start with:

```
//Explodey.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

//

#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc,_TCHAR* argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

I have a few questions about it:

- Why is the main function _tmain instead of main?
- I'd thought the `argv` parameter was supposed to be `char* argv[]` instead of `_TCHAR`.
- What's `stdafx.h`?

This doesn't really feel like the same C++ I'm used to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

Comment: True, but at the time of posting, I didn't even know main() was a legal main function in Visual C++.

Comment: I understand.  Just trying to help out the next programmer who comes along with a similar question.  The answers in the other question are a little more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here for _tmain... etc.

[What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

stdafx.h is a precompiled header (optional) for Windows applications. More here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header

Comment: If you remove the precompiled header include you must also change the project settings under "Precompiled Headers" or you'll get compile errors.