# Why do we have different versions of main functions in c++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

How the void main(...), int main(..) and int _tmain() differs. They all are single entry and single exit systems. But in what situations we use these start-up functions?

Comment: AFAIK _tmain is Microsoft specific...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c

Comment: And `void main()` is very old C++.

Comment: `void main()` was *never* valid C++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c

Comment: `void main()` has also never been valid C (except that an implementation may support it as an extension). The same standard (the 1989 ANSI C standard) that introduced the `void` keyword defined the two valid forms: `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent. Certain book authors invented the false idea that `void main()` is valid; I'd like to know why.

Comment: @Keith: I assume that they had previously been writing `main` functions with implicit-int return value, that fell off the end of the function instead of returning a defined value. At some point their compiler complained about a non-void function not returning a value, and the laziest possible way to "fix" that was to change `main` to return `void`, disregarding that it's still not valid. I believe that a common implementation detail to support both required forms of `main` is just to not check the signature of `main` at all.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Would it have been enough to just add int? As the standard explicitly mentions that the return statement is not necessary => return 0 [§3.6.1.5]

Comment: @MFH: the C99 standard says that, but we're talking about the era of the C89 standardization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void main()` is invalid; the C++ standard requires `main` to return `int`. Some compilers let you get away with it.

`int main()` is one of the two standard forms. The other is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, which can be used to receive command-line arguments. Implementations may permit other forms, but are not required to -- but all such forms *must* return `int`.

`int _tmain()` is specific to Microsoft.

Comment: nm. you're totally right. 3.6.1 p2

Comment: [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section 3.6.1 [basic.start.main]; `int main(int argc)` is not one of the required forms.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why different implementations support different entry points (or choices of entry points) is that different OSes or environments have different ways of running programs, or different ways of passing argument information into the program.

There are two kinds of C++ implementation:

"hosted" implementations assume the existence of some kind of OS. On hosted implementations, `main` is required in conforming programs and must return `int`.

"freestanding" implementations don't assume the existence of an OS. On freestanding implementations it's up to the implementation whether to require `main` or not, but the standard does still say that if `main` is required then it must return `int`.

It's common practice for implementations to provide the facilities of a hosted implementation, but to allow entry points other than `main`. This conforms to the standard for a hosted implementation, provided that a conforming program that *does* define `main` is accepted. In effect the implementation allows (as an extension) certain non-conforming programs with no `main` function provided they contain instead the implementation-defined alternative. Technically I think it must diagnose the "error", but in practice nobody would use such an extension by accident, so they probably don't want to see a diagnostic.

Similarly, a conforming implementation can accept a program containing `void main`. Again, for the implementation to conform it must diagnose that the program doesn't conform.

The meaning of a non-conforming program that the implementation accepts anyway, is up to the implementation.

`_tmain` is a MS extension. It is an alias for `main` in narrow-character builds and `wmain` in wide-character builds. `wmain` is also a MS extension, it's like `main` except that `argv` are provided as wide strings instead of narrow strings. So this is an example of an environment where there are two different ways to give arguments to programs, depending whether or not the program handles characters outside the range of narrow characters (i.e. outside the 8-bit code page).