# argv[1] contains only the first letter of the first command-line argument in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between _tmain() and main() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

I have a console application, which takes one command line parameter.

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...
    printf("Path: %s\n", argv[1]);
        ...
}
```

When I run the program with an argument (`myprogram.exe D:\myfolder\myfile`), it prints `Path: D` instead of `Path: D:\myfolder\myfile`.

How should I change the procedure for extracting first command-line parameter (`argv[1]`) so that it returns the full path, not just the first letter?

I tried to put the path in quotes (`myprogram.exe "D:\myfolder\myfile"`), but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try between simple quotes ? Or escaping the backslashes (`myprogram.exe "D:\\myfolder\\myfile"`) ?

Comment: It's not the quotes.  `argv` is a character array, not a string array.  You are explicitly selecting the item at index 1 of that array, which is the single character `D`.

Comment: Just wondering.  In console applications, I've always used `main` (rather than `_tmain`), and I've never had any problems.

Comment: @DanPuzey `argv` is an array of pointers to C-style strings.  If this is not what `_tmain` actually receives a `char*` or a `char[]`, then his code would crash, not just display the first character.\

Comment: I tried it now. Escaping backslashes didn't help. If I put the path in simple quotes (`myprogram.exe 'D:\\myfolder\\myfile'`), then `Path: '` is displayed.

Comment: @Mat Having read the response you cite, I come to the conclusion that you should _never_ use `_tmain`, because it cannot work.  Use either `main`, or if you're willing to be Microsoft specific, `wmain`.

Comment: @DanPuzey So how do I retrieve the first string in the array of strings (in this particular case) ?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: ignore me; James Kanze rightly pointed out I am talking rubbish :]

Comment: Shouldn't `_tmain` take a `TCHAR *argv[]` parameter anyway? Not that changing that alone will help you.

Answer (score 6):

Use `_tprintf` instead of `printf`. Your program is almost certainly set to compile as `UNICODE` and, therefore, each "character" takes up two bytes.

You call `printf` which operates on single byte characters. The second byte happens to be 0, and so `printf` thinks it reached the end of the string since a zero byte is considered the termination of a string.

And make sure your `argv` is declared as `TCHAR` and not `char`. Be consistent: either use the `TCHAR` routines, or don't. But don't mix unless you have a **very** good reason (i.e. you know what you're doing and you are gearing up to do some magic). Chances are you don't and you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio C++ has a special way of dealing with Unicode support. Macros in [tchar.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) expand to normal or wide char versions of the symbols depending on the project setting. So `_tprintf` expands to `printf` or `wprintf`. It seems like you're trying to use `printf`, if your project settings enable the Unicode support, what you're running into is the exact problem to expect. Have a look at tchar.h and try using `_tprintf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio the main function usually takes up the arguments of type wchar. If that is the case try outputting via the wprintf function as:

```
wprintf("Path : %S", argv[1]);
```

Notice the capital 'S'. If you substitute this with a lowercase 's' it will print the first character only. That is how the wide characters work. you should read more about them on the msdn forum.

Comment: No - it depends on the compilation and project settings. If he's using _tmain he should be using the tchar routines everywhere, consistently, unless there's a good reason (e.g. parsing and displaying non-UNICODE input from UNICODE app or vice-versa)