# VS2012 - Why is a function in the main file not visible in _tmain?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm fairly new to C++, and I'm starting out with this in a terminal application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 1 )
    {
        printHelp();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printHelp()
{
    cout << "Usage:";
    cout << "vmftomap [filename]";
}
```

However, I get the error "'printHelp' identifier not found" in _tmain. Since the function is declared directly beneath main, I'm assuming this is a namespace issue? I have read up on namespaces but I don't know what would apply in this case, since I haven't actually explicitly defined one for printHelp().

Comment: Consider this post: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your function before you invoke it. It is not necessary to *define* it, but the compiler must at least know about its existence in the moment it has to resolve a function call, which means it must have met a declaration for it during the processing of your translation unit (i.e. `.cpp` file):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Declaration
void printHelp();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 1 )
    {
        printHelp();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// Definition
void printHelp()
{
    cout << "Usage:";
    cout << "vmftomap [filename]";
}
```

Of course, you could directly define the `printHelp()` function before `main()` instead, thus making it visible to the compiler at the point the function call is made:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Definition
void printHelp()
{
    cout << "Usage:";
    cout << "vmftomap [filename]";
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 1 )
    {
        printHelp();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I'm used to programming where functions can come anywhere in the file and the compiler will find them, so I didn't think about this possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In C++, files are parsed top-to-bottom. With a few exceptions, identifiers have to be declared before they are used. This means you must move the definition of `printHelp()` before `_tmain()`, or add a forward declaration above `_tmain()`:

```
void printHelp();
```

Answer (score 0):

The function has to be defined before using it.

Move printHelp above _tmain.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function in c++, before the call, you must either:

- have a prototype of the function
- have the definition of the whole function

in your case, you have neither.