# Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location cause by cin command

Tags: c++, 64-bit

The issue i am facing is bit confusing as I was experiencing **Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location...** at run-time when build through Win32 configuration (on Win7-SP1 64bit / VS2010 / 4G RAM)

My app using a library and asking user to input but the **cin** command in my code raising the above run-time exception when code reaches to cin statement. So to make sure what i found, created a test project as following only code and verify the **cin** command raising same exception :

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 cout<<"Please enter ?\n";
 string input = "test";

 cin >> input; //This code causing runtime exception

 return 0;
}
```

I Google it and then modify the code to build with x64, which helps me to avoid this exception, so I modify my original code to 64bit and successfully able to run on cin command.

But when I change back the config to win32 and build the above exception is no more occurring from both in sample-app and in original app.

So I would like to know: if someone had face same what I am experiencing ?

- Whats wrong on 1st time when I build with win32 ?
- And also if the code is currently running successfully with win32 (after reverting back from x64), is it really doing fine or anything just mixed with something to make it work for time being ?

Thnaks

Comment: and if you do: string input; cin >> input; ?

Comment: try clearing your project and rebuild in win32. This should at least clear the fact some fragments would be left from x64-build.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to the use of UTF16 caused by [_tmain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895894)

Have you tried using [std::wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402918) or a normal (Non-Microsoft) main?