# Main method is different to those in tutorials

Tags: c++, visual-c++, program-entry-point

So I am starting with c++ (i am trying to broaden my mind with new languages) but I came across a little issue which confuses me more than what I guess it should...

Using Visual Studio Express 2012, I created a console win32 application in C++ and this is my main method decleration:

```
// TestApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

however, since I dont know anything about c++, I searched for some tuts online and all of them had there declerations setup in a different manner

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout<<"HEY, you, I'm alive! Oh, and Hello World!\n";
  cin.get();
}
```

and

```
// my first program in C++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

I tried typing in the "std::cout", but it wouldnt accept it, 
could someone just clarify why and the significance of the difference ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The main method can be define with or without parameters. It all depends upon what you are using your application for.

Take a look at this: https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fmainf.htm

Also for your program you need to have a return value

```
// my first program in C++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

is (at least I think so) a Windows only library and compiler depending way of declaring the main function.

Definitly not wrong is to declare main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //do something
    return 0;
}
```

or like this:

```
int main()
{
    //do something
    return 0;
}
```

This is definitly proper C++ and you can use this universially.

Answer (score 0):

C++ programs may have one of two beginnings:

```
        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

or

```
        int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
```

The first of these gets its arguments (argv) as ANSI charachers, while the second gets "wide" characters -- generally UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on the platform.

Microsoft define a framework to allow you make code that can compile with either ANSI or wide characters.

```
        int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
```

Behind the scenes, they have something like this:

```
        #if defined UNICODE
            #define _tmain wmain
            #define TCHAR wchar_t
        #else
            #define _tmain main
            #define TCHAR char
        #endif
```

They also have helper functions like `_tprintf()` and `_tcscpy()`.

NOTE: as pointed out by others, the argc and argv params are optional, so you can also have

```
        int main()
```

and

```
        int wmain()
```

and (for Microsoft and compatible compilers)

```
        int _tmain()
```

Also note that while `_tmain()` is not strictly portable, you can easily create your own `#define` macros if you want to be portable to other platforms.

Comment: No. `wmain` is not legal C++ – it’s a Microsoft extension, same as `_tmain`.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I thought wmain() had been added to the standard, but a quick search did not reveal any support for that.  Clearly I've been doing too much Windows programming lately.