# Error Reading Command Line Arguments In Win32 Console Application?

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line-arguments

I need help because I am not getting the expected output while attempting to read the command line arguments. It is really strange because I copied and pasted the code into a regular console application and it works as expected. It is worth noting that I am running Windows 7 and in visual studio I set the command line argument to be test.png

Win32 Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Questions: why doesn't this work (but the one in helloworld does)
    //What are object files? In unix I can execute using ./ but here I need to go to debug in top directory and execute the .exe
    printf("hello\n");
    printf("First argument: %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Second argument: %s\n", argv[1]);

    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
First Argument: C
Second Argument: t
```

I tried creating a simple console application and it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int arg, char* argv[])
{
    printf("hello\n");
    printf("First argument: %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Second argument: %s\n", argv[1]);

    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
First Argument: path/to/hello_world.exe
Second Argument: test.png
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: At a guess I would say you have a Unicode build but are trying to print the strings as if they are Ansi.

Comment: @JonathanPotter How does *that* happen and still link? Or is that the issue in the first place (doesn't build)? I agree with you, i just don't see how it even builds. odd.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Me either, although there's no guarantee the code shown here is *actually* the code being compiled.

Comment: It is being compiled...I didn't do anything major. These are the templates provided by visual studio 2013. I literally just wrote the printf inside.

Comment: @JonathanPotter as usual, excellent point.

Comment: why are using stdio and C++.iostream perhaps?

Comment: @user2316667 If Mr.Potter is correct (and it certainly seems likely) change `_tmain` to `main()`, and change your project settings on the main project-config page to be MultiByte rather than Unicode. then rebuild the entire project. Make sure to make that change for *all* build configurations (debug and release).

Comment: I changed it to stdio, builds and same, correct result.

Comment: For future readers: I messed up. I actually did change the main function from TCHAR* argv[] to char* argv[] for some reason. So it was NOT the original template. Not that that was really my problem anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_tmain` is just a macro that changes depending on whether you compile with Unicode or ASCII, if it is ASCII then it will place `main` and if it is Unicode then it will place `wmain`

If you want the correct Unicode declaration that accepts command line arguments in Unicode then you must declare it to accept a Unicode string like this:

`int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]);`

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895894/1496443)

Another issue with your code is that `printf` expects an ASCII C Style string and not a Unicode. Either use `wprintf` or use `std::wcout` to print a Unicode style string.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    //Questions: why doesn't this work (but the one in helloworld does)
    //What are object files? In unix I can execute using ./ but here I need to go to debug in top directory and execute the .exe
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
    std::wcout << "First argument: " << argv[0] << "\n";
    std::wcout << "Second argument: " << argv[1] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: I changed the main function to the one you described but I still only get the first letter. Great link though.

Comment: @user2316667 Check your settings that you are compiling it using Unicode. If using Visual Studio then right click the project, `properties` and in the `General` tab make sure `Character Set` is set to `Use Unicode Character set`.

Comment: Yes. It was always set to Use Unicode Character Set. [edit] Not that I knew - just looked at it. And still the same problem. Note that the function works with main. But I'm really curious about getting it to work with unicode. I mean, it should be working, right?

Comment: As per the link, as expected, win32 application works perfectly when I use the main function. This may be complete misuse of terminology, but does one 'enter' in unicode or multibyte character set?

Comment: @user2316667 Yes, `printf` expects an ASCII C-Style string.

Comment: For its identifier, that is correct. So it must not have read "%s" incorrectly and printed out a byte instead. There exists wprintf though. Works like a charm. Apparently append L infront of literal strings. I really appreciate your time Caesar. Thanks so much.