# c++ program using too much memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have a c++ program that makes a simulation. The simulation is large. It needs to be ran several times.

I probably didn't take into account some memory management guidelines like passing arguments by reference to functions to avoid copies of the same data to be wasting memory, and maybe other techniques I don't even know about. But it is too late to redo the whole program again (or maybe it won't even help).

I have a program

```
void main(){

//Simulation consuming a lot of memory.

};
```

I would like something like

```
void main(){
   for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){   
     //Simulation consuming a lot of memory (depending on i).
   };
};
```

But in such a way that after each loop of the **for** the memory used inside is released (probably except that which is used for the program and the counter i of the for).

The memory holds fine for one repetition of the loop but not for two.

I there a way this can be done?

Comment: Your loop should accomplish that, provided the simulation does not leak memory. It sounds like it does, so you have to clean up the leaks.

Comment: This is way too vague. Are you leaking memory, or do the simulation just naturally require lots of memory? If you are leaking memory, you need to fix that first (look up smart pointers). BTW, `void main()` is not valid C++.

Comment: A memory leak scenario but you must share some of your code with us, so we can tell you where to release memory or what techniques will be useful for you.

Comment: @Adam The problem is that I don't even know what is a memory leak (I can guess from the plain meaning of the words, but not idea what it means technically).

Comment: This is called memory leaks. You reserve memory, use it, but don't dispose it when you are done, so it's a snow ball that just keeps growing. You have to look after how exactly all this is happening.

Comment: In c++, what Havenard said means that you have a `new` without a matching `delete`.

Comment: @Sachamora The code is huge. :S

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Adam I see... I have lots of "new", and no delete.

Comment: @Adam I suppose that matching delete should be for the specific object the "new" created, isn't it? There is not way to do a global delete?

Comment: It sounds like a proper clean up is above your head. Another option is to run each iteration in another process. When a process exits all of its resources are cleaned up by the OS. The details on how to do this depend on your OS.

Comment: @Adam Windows 8, Visual Studio, Visual C++ ?

Comment: @Karene correct. Another option is to use smart pointers. These handle deletion for you automatically. Look up `shared_ptr`. That might be the easiest way to fix the code.

Comment: @Adam Searching that now.

Comment: not a Windows guy, can't help you with the best way to start a process there. But there should be a crapload of info online. Memory management is easy to screw up, and you sound like a novice. I'd try the process method first because it lets you leave the sim code untouched. Then go yell at whoever wrote it.

Comment: @Adam I will have to yell at myself. I wrote that mess.

Comment: @Karene use automatic allocation as much as possible (i.e. replace pointers to new'd stuff, with non-pointer variables)

Comment: In that case, you should go back and fix the leaks. `delete` any pointer you're done with, or use `shared_ptr` when you want automatic management. Don't use globals.

Comment: @Adam What if I make an object that has a single function that contains the whole code of the (of the main() of the) simulation. Then in my main (inside the "for") I create that object with the shared_ptr and make it run its function. Would the destruction of the object destroy also all the memory allocation that its function made?

Comment: Matt is right, there is a growing movement that there are very few reasons for a "naked" `new`. In other words, every `new` should go directly into something like a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: yes, a `shared_ptr` deletes whatever it points to when the last reference goes out of scope.

Comment: @Adam Good! Then I will try that. It would be less changes to do than to fix all the "new" that are all around the program (many of them!).

Comment: @Karene Um, it won't work the way you want it to. It'd delete the empty object but not anything allocated by the function.

Comment: @T.C Ohww... Then I guess I will need to write another c++ program that runs the .exe of my simulation several times. The memory seems to hold well for one run of the simulation. For two passes it fills up.

Comment: I don't know if you're coming from a Java or C# background but my suggestion is to just stop using `new` in C++. If you need dynamic containers, data structures, or strings look first in the C++ standard library. When you have no other choice but to use `new` you have to think about resource management for your objects. That means construction, copying, assignment, and destruction.

Comment: @Karene: writing another c++ program may be overkill... your OS shell (e.g. `bash` - `i=0; while (( $i < 20 )); do ./your_app $i; let i+=1; done`, `cmd.exe`) probably allows this very easily - you can accept `i` ala `int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) { if (argc != 2) exit(1); int i = atoi(argv[1]); ... }`

Comment: @TonyD Could you put this as an answer. I don't think I am understanding it. Does that go in a bash file?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thanks. I shall take it into account in the future. I am actually coming from not using an actual programming language for more than 20 years. I just began learning C++ four weeks ago. I have rough theoretical knowledge of OOP but zero concrete practice.

Comment: @Karene: done... hope it's clearer now.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ***UNIX/Linux***, you could create a bash shell script to call your C++ program the required number of times, say `run_my_app.sh` with the following content:

```
i=0
while (( $i < 10000 )); do
    ./my_app $i
    let i+=1
done
```

Then make it executable with `chmod +x run_my_app.sh`.

---

On ***Windows***, do the same for the `cmd.exe` "shell", creating `run_my_app.bat` with:

```
for /l %i in (0,1,9999) do my_app %i
```

You can add the full path to my_app if you need to, e.g.: `c:\dir1\dir2\my_app` instead of `my_app`.  You don't need to do anything to make it executable - that's implied by the `.bat` extension.

---

Then modify your ***C++ program*** as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
         std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " i\n"
              "run the simulation iteration number <i>.\n";
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    ...simulation...
}
```

Comment: This is for Linux isn't it? I only have Windows at the moment. :S Thanks, though.

Comment: @Karene: Windows version added.

Comment: My main looks like int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[])

When I added your code, it said that it cannot convert from _TCHAR* from constant fiels

Comment: @Karene: my code follows the C++ Standard... _TCHAR is not Standard C++ and I don't know about it.  I can only suggest you try a different compiler or google/ask about that problem separately.  You can presumably find an example of a `_tmain`/`_TCHAR` monstrosity's arguments being parsed without much effort.  Cheers.

Comment: It is working now. But I am having a problem. The atoi is ony taking the first digit of the %%i.

Comment: @Karene: that sounds very strange... a bit of searching suggests this tmain/TCHAR thing is doing something non-Standard: accepting "wide" characters (unicode) - there's a discussion about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c).  I don't know how to work with unicode strings - not something I've ever had to do and frankly the idea of wading into that mess sends a shiver down my spine, but hopefully now you know what the problem is you can find a solution or ask a question about tmain and unicode.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with those tmain and Tchar. I changed them to main and char, and now it worked. The argv was only inputting the first character of the argument.

Comment: @Karene: thanks for letting me know.  Hope the simulation's running ok then.  Cheers.