# C++ argv[] not being passed fully

Tags: c++, arguments

```
// Type the determine year in the command line as an argument.
// This program then prints the months and days for that year.

//Known Error argv[1] = the first digit of year,

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void printYear(int year);

int _tmain(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
    string str;//varible used to exit the program

    if (argc == 1 ){//checks to see if the years were inputted corrected
        std::cout << "Please input Year in the command line. Exiting.." << std::endl;
        cout << "Please type anything to continue..." << endl;
        cin >> str;
        return 1;
    }

    int Year = 1982;
    int numYears = argc-1;

    cout << "Number of Argments Loaded : " << numYears << endl;
    for (int x = 1; x <= numYears; x++){
        Year = atoi(argv[x]);
        cout << "Year : " << argv[x] << endl;
        cout << "Year is " << Year << endl;
        printYear(Year);
    }

    cout << "Please type anything to continue..." << endl;
    cin >> str;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently learning C++ and this is one of my assignments. I just spent a better half of a day looking into this to no avail.

printYear() has been tested with numerous years and is functional. The only remanding error left is with argv[]. It only returns the first digit of the year inputted, which is fine if you want to research years 0-9. Any tips or trick you guys mind passing me? (I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio fyi)

Command line

```
calender.exe 1982
```

returns with

```
Number of Arguments Loaded : 1
Year : 1
Year is 1
```

Repetitive code I know but I'm troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is [`_tmain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895894/603688). If you have unicode enabled it tries to give you wide (UTF-16) characters, so every other character will be `\0`. To fix this you want to call it `main` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the arguments are passed as UNICODE strings however you process them in the program as ASCII strings.